# facebook graph api {page}/links only returns for 60 days

Tags: python, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm managing a Facebook page in which I'm also analyzing it's insights. We own the page and every post on the page feed(page doesn't allow other users to post). I'm doing an analysis on all of the posts that we've every created. 
I've been using {page}/posts edge to get the post ids but found out that it only returns a subset of the data. Then I tried {page}/links and {page}/videos because these are the post types I'm mostly interested in. The video edge works great; it gave me all of the videos ids from the page. However, {page}/links only returned 2 months worth of link ids. 
Here is a sample GET I'm using (I'm trying to get the post ids from 10/2014 to 12/2014):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/{actual_page_id}/links?fields=id,created_time&since=1414175236&until=1419445636&access_token=[The_actual_access_token]
```

But I get an empty result string:

```
{"data": []}
```

And when I set the date with in the 2 months frame I can get proper response.

My question is: Is there a way to get ALL of the Facebook page posts ids that we have created? I've tried to set limits and paging but none have worked. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The Below snippet should solve your issue, It uses [Facepy](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy) and handles paging on its own.

```
from facepy import GraphAPI
import json

access = '<access_token>'

graph = GraphAPI(access)
page_id= '<page_id>'
data= graph.get(page_id+ "/posts?fields=id", page=True, retry=5)

data1=[]

for i in data:
    data1.append(i)
    print data1
```